# How to keep a node server running after logout or without logging in into any user after system restart on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, service, pm2

I went through many articles related to this but couldn't find a robust solution. Tried using [pm2-windows-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service) but still the service stops on user logout.

Is it to do something with the **pm2_home** environment variable which has user specific path set and needs to be made generic? I am not sure about that.

Thanks in advance!